# tomcat port URL restriction

Tags: java, security, url, tomcat, port

I am trying to configure tomcat so that my application will be accessible via two different ports, say 8080 and 8980, but certain URLs will be accessible via only 8980.

The reason is that the web tier uses 8080 and I don't want certain URLs to be exposed to the outside world. I also don't want to configure web servers to restrict this, because of the coupling it creates between the app and the web tier.

I understand that I can configure two connectors and then programmatically block calls to the URLs based on the port, but:

1. I would rather not hard-code the port, as it may be changed in
   the future in the server.xml
2. I want this same behaviour in various
   applications in the organization, and don't want all developers to
   need to implement this separately.

Is there a configuration where I can, perhaps, exclude certain URL patterns from a connector that is defined in server.xml?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just put a reverse HTTP proxy (e.g. Apache HTTP server with its AJP proxy) in front of your Tomcat and configure access policies there.

Answer (score 0):

In tomcat, you can define multiple services with different connector ports and engine settings, but an application will only be served by one engine, so you'd have to deploy your application multiple times.

For use cases like yours, tomcat is too limited, but this functionality is usually deferred to a Reverse proxy, e.g. apache or nginx.

You could for example let your tomcat serve on port 8980, and configure an apache to reverse proxy all /app calls on port 8080, except the internals:

```
Listen 8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
   ProxyPass /app/internal !
   ProxyPass /app http://localhost:8980/app
</VirtualHost>
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass